# Sort the sorted List after a second criterion

Tags: sorting, groovy

I have an List  resultList and I want to sort the list after the content of the object[]. So I want to sort it first after the account 'row[11]' and then vehicle 'row[1]'. How can I do the second sort with Groovy?

```
        Object[] row = (Object[]) resultList.get(i);
        String account = row[11];
        String  vehicle = row[1];
```

**Example**

```
 Account     Vehicle

     HKB         300 - PB
     HKV         400 - PDAAA
     HMN         200 - PBC200
     HZA         155 - PCL
     HZA         160 - PGA100
     HZAB        165 - PGA100
     HZAC        170 - PGA100
```

**Code**

```
int execute(List <Object[]> resultList) {

    Object[] row = null;
    resultList = resultList.sort{ a,b -> a[11] <=> b[11]};
    //Then here I want to sort the sorted resultList after the vehicle also second group.       
    for (int i=resultList.size()-1; i >= 0; i--) {
        row = (Object[]) resultList.get(i);
        String account = row[11];
        String  vehicle = row[1];

    }

    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Can you come up with some example input, and expected output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think you just need to replace:

```
resultList = resultList.sort{ a,b -> a[11] <=> b[11]};
```

with

```
resultList = resultList.sort { a, b ->
    a[11] <=> b[11] ?: a[1] <=> b[1]
}
```